# .Net HttpListenerRequest response is not working with Ajax in chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, google-chrome

In my code I am doing the following:

```
                        response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                        StringWriter stringToWrite = new StringWriter();

                        respose_example = getData();


                        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer outSeralizeList = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Registers>));
                        outSeralizeList.Serialize(stringToWrite, respose_example);
                        string responseString = stringToWrite.ToString();

                        // Construct a response.
                        response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
                        // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
                        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                        Stream output = response.OutputStream;

                        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        // You must close the output stream.
                        output.Close();
```

In my browser code I am doing the following:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "", false);
var command = new commandObject();
command.command = "xml";
try {
  xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(command));
} catch(e){
  alert(e);
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
DOMException {message: "A network error occurred.", name: "NetworkError", code: 19, stack: "Error: A network error occurred.↵    at getXML (ht…rElement.onclick (http://127.0.0.1:7000/:403:164)", INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1…}
code: 19
message: "A network error occurred."
name: "NetworkError"
stack: "Error: A network error occurred.↵    at getXML (http://127.0.0.1:7000/:84:19)↵    at create_table (http://127.0.0.1:7000/:182:22)↵    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (http://127.0.0.1:7000/:403:164)"
__proto__: DOMException
```

Not sure why it works on in FF. I wish chrome would give more details.

Comment: Setting asynch to false is a bad idea. Use a callback/promise instead. If you press F12 in firefox (with firebug) and in Chrome and check out the xhr request in the console. Can you see any differences in the POST ed values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After recoding my code and using an asynchronous ajax call chrome seemed to work. I guess synchronous Ajax is broken on chrome.